# How to make current view a scrollview? iOS / Objective C

Tags: objective-c, ios, uiscrollview, scrollview

I have a view (that is actually part of a UINavigationControllers view) that i want to make a scrollview.

how do i do that?

could i do something like this:

```
UIScrollView * content = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.bounds];
self.view = content
```

(obviously that doesn't work, but is there a way to do it like that)?

Comment: You **can** assingn a scroll view to `self.view`...

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is, you have to implement delegates, and set the contentSize. The best tutorial on scrollViews ever I found is:

http://www.raywenderlich.com/10518/how-to-use-uiscrollview-to-scroll-and-zoom-content

You are on a good way!

Answer (score 0):

You can create the scroll view programmatically like you do and then add the existing view as a subview of this new scroll view, examine `addSubview:` (which works on all `UIView`s and subclasses like `UIScrollView` as well). I won't say this is the solution or even a clean one for that matter, but if you read about `addSubview:` you can at least figure out how to have a view live inside a scroll view...